# No observations available

Tags: ros, object-recognition-kitchen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to make a mesh

```
rosrun object_recognition_reconstruction mesh_object --all --visualize --commit
```

but a got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/tomas/ws/src/ork_reconstruction/apps/mesh_object", line 191, in <module>
simple_mesh_session(dbs, session, args)
File "/home/tomas/ws/src/ork_reconstruction/apps/mesh_object", line 87, in simple_mesh_session
raise RuntimeError("There are no observations available.")
RuntimeError: There are no observations available.
```

What does it mean? Is something wrong with my database? I normally uploaded .bag file before so I dont understand why no observations are available.

[edit]
So I realized the problem is probably while uploading.

```
rosrun object_recognition_capture upload -i final.bag -n 'box' box juice --commit
```

Gives these errors:

```
Stored new object with id: 46c9ea4d3baf8b3dc11b0e40e6001650
Loading bag with : final.bag
running graph
Opening bag: final.bag
Inserting frame: 0
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (code) in imencode, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/highgui    /src/loadsave.cpp, line 430
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/tomas/ws/src/ork_capture/apps/upload", line 145, in <module>
session = compute_for_bag_with_mask_pose(bag, obj, args)
File "/home/tomas/ws/src/ork_capture/apps/upload", line 105, in compute_for_bag_with_mask_pose
run_plasm(args, plasm, locals=vars())
File "/home/tomas/ws/src/ecto/python/ecto/opts.py", line 85, in run_plasm
sched.execute(options.niter)
ecto.CellException:            exception_type  CellException
[cell_name] = db_inserter

[cell_type] = object_recognition_core::prototypes::ObservationInserter

[function_name] = process_with_only_these_inputs

[type] = cv::Exception

[what] = /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:430: error: (-215) code in function imencode
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222043/no-observations-available./) by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2015-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was an image encoding problem. It should have been fixed: https://github.com/wg-perception/capture/pull/23

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2017-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0